# How to implement Z Gesture to dismiss an alert or go to previous screen in voiceOver for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gesture, voiceover

To dismiss an alert while in voiceOver mode, Z gesture is used. Anyone please let me know how to implement that for my project or provide a link which has an example for how to implement that in objective-c?

Comment: Method to use for is accessibilityPerformEscape,    
Return Value: 
YES if the modal view is successfully dismissed; otherwise, NO. By default, this method returns NO.
Discussion: 
Implement this method on an element or containing view that can be revealed modally or in a hierarchy. When a VoiceOver user performs a dismiss action, this method dismisses the view. For example, you might implement this method for a popover in order to give users a deliberate dismiss action to perform that closes the popover.

Comment: I got above hint somewhere but no example implementation.

Answer (score 0):

To dismiss an alert view thanks to the scrub gesture, override accessibilityPerformEscape() **in the alert view itself**.

I've provided the implementation for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52505599/3825084) but it's written in swift : the code isn't complex at all so that you can easily translate it into ObjC.